# Spring Boot static resources

Tags: spring-boot, static-content

Всем привет. Не подскажете, почему происходит так, что статические ресурсы каким-то странным образом определяются? В моем случае происходит так

В папке src/main/resources/templates у меня лежит index.ftl

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>FTL Document</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/myjs.js"></script>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="f()">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

В папке /src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/static лежит myjs.js

```
function f() {
alert("Привет");
}
```

Это все. И конечно ftl файлик на меня ругается, так как здесь ../static/myjs.js ничего нет. И это логично - в папке /src/main/resources папки static у меня нет. Но когда я запускаю сервер, все работает, по кнопке работает эта функция. И меня раздражает то, что если я вместо папки
/resources/META-INF/resources/static создам /resources/static и положу туда js файлик, то в таком случае, данный файл не обнаруживается после запуска сервера. Получаю

GET http://localhost:8080/static/myjs.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 2):

Создать надо такой конфиг

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}
}
```